# WebBrowser InvokeScript "eval" bug

Tags: javascript, c#, console-application, webbrowser-control, eval

So I'm trying to run javascript code on website through my WebBrowser in console application but I came across weird bug. This is my code:

```
object[] mathArgs = { "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'someID\',\'\')', 0)" };
mainWebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", mathArgs);
```

and after this I receive: 
"There was an error in the script on this page:
Line: 1 
Char: 1
Expected char ')'
Code: 0"
Funny thing is it works well in WinForms project, there is problem in console app. Am I missing something? Additionally, it's code that works on page I work on.

Answer (score 0):

If your code work without any problem use the "ScriptErrorsSuppressed" property to ignore JS errors :

```
WebBrowser mainWebBrowser = new WebBrowser {ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true};

// Navigation code gose here
object[] mathArgs = { "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'someID\',\'\')', 0)" };
mainWebBrowser?.Document?.InvokeScript("eval", mathArgs);
```